# Firebase: calling setUserID() does not seem to work the second time it is called

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

As the title says, I am calling setUserID() twice in my App:

```
FirebaseAnalytics.Analytics.setUserID("x")
```

This seems to work the first time (I am seeing the set userID in the debug view of the Firebase site). The secnod time it I am calling (I pass a different userID of course), the debug view of Firebase keeps logging the events with the same userID as before.

I am running on iOS with the latest version of Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't occur for me on more recent versions of analytics:

```
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '5.20.2'
  pod 'Fabric', '1.9.0'
  pod 'Crashlytics', '3.12.0'
```

I am calling `Firebase.Analytics.setUserID`.
I'd suggest updating your version.
There is however an issue I'm experiencing using the DebugView whereby UserProperties and User Ids aren't being shown to reset when being set to nil.